# Accelerometer is not getting called

Tags: gps, accelerometer, restart, cmmotionmanager

I am doing a somewhat strange implementation. My application uses GPS data continuously and using that I have to do some task. Also I have implemented accelerometer stuff to detect whether device is stationary or moving. When the device is stationary I stop GPS fetching by calling `stopUpdatingLocation`, and when device is moving I call `startUpdatingLocation`. This works fine both in the foreground and background.

But I want my application to be started in the background when the device is restarted. This works fine. I have added "voip" key in plist and in `applicationDidFinishLaunch` I have started GPS fetching code and started accelerometer.

But I found that once the device is kept stationary (`stopUpdatingLocation`), the accelerometer is not getting called. Because of that I cannot detect device movement. The accelerometer callback is not getting called. Here is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
    mMotionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    if (mMotionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {
        mMotionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0/10.0;
       mOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [mMotionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:mOperationQueue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //[self onDeviceMotion];
                [mAccelerometerReadings addObject:  data];
                [self updateViewsWithFilteredAcceleration:data.acceleration];
            });
        }];
```

Can someone help me solve this? Is it possible?